# backpropagation neural network with discrete output

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am working through the xor example with a three layer back propagation network. When the output layer has a sigmoid activation, an input of (1,0) might give 0.99 for a desired output of 1 and an input of (1,1) might give 0.01 for a desired output of 0.

But what if want the output to be discrete, either 0 or 1, do I simply set a threshold in between at 0.5? Would this threshold need to be trained like any other weight?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can of course put a threshold after the output neuron which makes the values after 0.5 as 1 and, vice versa, all the outputs below 0.5 as zero. I suggest to don't hide the continuous output with a discretization threshold, because an output of 0.4 is less "zero" than a value of 0.001 and this difference can give you useful information about your data.

Answer (score 0):

Do the training without threshold, ie. computes the error on a example by using what the neuron networks outputs, without thresholding it.

Another little detail : you use a transfer function such as sigmoid ? The sigmoid function returns values in [0, 1], but 0 and 1 are asymptote ie. the sigmoid function can come close to those values but never reach them. A consequence of this is that your neural network can not exactly output 0 or 1 ! Thus, using sigmoid times a factor a little above 1 can correct this. This and some other practical aspects of back propagation are discussed here http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf